# Create custom integration setting for slash commands

Tags: slack

Can you create custom integration settings for slash commands?

[I want to create extra config like these. E.g. Such as where to send the email to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhuhZ.png)

I am now hosting the api on heroku and have current configuration in the settings. Such as the from_email, to_email, smtp_port, etc... 
Is it possible to create integration settings so I can set these values in the slash command configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding it is currently not possible to add custom integration options to your own Slack apps, like e.g. the Twitter app has.

The Slack team might add this feature in the future (and I hope they do). In the meantime you have three alternatives.

1. Let the user enter the integration option on your website along with the "Add to Slack" button.
2. Direct the user to a custom webpage for changing his settings
3. Provide some additional features with your slash command that lets the user change settings, e.g. `/command set smtp example.com`